# Object is reinserted into database immediately after delete (DbLinq)

Tags: c#, mysql, linq-to-sql, dblinq

I have a MySql database, whose general structure looks like this:

```
Manufacturer <== ProbeDefinition <== ImagingSettings
  ElementSettings  ====^ ^==== ProbeInstance
```

I'm using InnoDB to allow foreign keys, and all foreign keys pointing to a `ProbeDefinition` have set `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

The issue I'm having is when I delete a `ProbeDefinition` in my code, it gets immediately reinserted. The cascading delete happens properly so other tables are cleared, but it seems that the LINQ to SQL may be sending an insert for no reason. Checking the ChangeSet property on the database shows 1 delete, and no inserts.

I'm using the following small bit of code to perform the delete:

```
database.ProbeDefinition.DeleteOnSubmit(probe);
database.SubmitChanges();
```

Logs in MySql show the following commands being executed when this is run:

```
BEGIN
use `wetscoprobes`; DELETE FROM wetscoprobes.probedefinition WHERE ID = 10
use `wetscoprobes`; INSERT INTO wetscoprobes.probedefinition (CenterFrequency, Elements, ID, IsPhased, ManufacturerID, Name, Pitch, Radius, ReverseElements) VALUES (9500000, 128, 10, 1, 6, 'Super Probe 2', 300, 0, 1) 
COMMIT /* xid=2424 */
```

What could cause this unnecessary `INSERT`? Note that deleting a `Manufacturer` in the exact same way deletes correctly, with the following log:

```
BEGIN 
use `wetscoprobes`; DELETE FROM wetscoprobes.manufacturer WHERE ID = 9 
COMMIT /* xid=2668 */
```

**Edit:** Upon further testing, it seems that this only happens after I've populated a ListBox with a list of `ProbeDefinition`s.

I tried running the above delete code before and after the following snippet had run:

```
var manufacturer = (Manufacturer)cbxManufacturer.SelectedItem;
var probes = manufacturer.ProbeDefinition;

foreach (var probe in probes)
{
    cbxProbeModel.Items.Add(probe);
}
```

The object gets deleted properly before said code has run, but anytime after this point, it performs an insert after the delete. Does it not like the fact that the object is referenced somewhere?

Here's the code I'm running to test deleting a definition from the intermediate window:

```
database.ProbeDefinition.DeleteOnSubmit(database.ProbeDefinition.Last())
database.SubmitChanges()
```

Comment: If another table is deleting just fine, it is most likely going to have something to do with your settings on the ProbeDefinition table in the LinqToSql designer.  Can you provide those settings?

Comment: I hadn't used the LinqToSql designer, rather the classes were generated using DbMetal.exe provided with DbLinq and I connected in code. Looking over the generated definitions from DbMetal, I don't see any code related to deleting...

Comment: @NickLarsen: I've updated the question with some more findings, in particular that only after having existing references to the object does the delete also perform the insert.

Comment: Have you tried using the Remove function instead of DeleteOnSubmit?

Comment: @NickLarsen: Remove didn't work. It removes the item client-side, but it still exists on the server (logs show a delete and insert again), and restarting the client makes the object reappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there are issues when there are multiple references to your object. Stepping through the DbLinq source, I learned that after a `DELETE` is completed, it steps through all other "watched" objects, looking for references.

In this case, I have multiple references through the table `database.ProbeDefinition` as well as through the manufacturer reference, `manufacturer.ProbeDefinition`. This isn't an issue till I have accessed objects through both methods. Using `Remove` can delete the reference from manufacturer, using `DeleteOnSubmit` will delete the the object from the table. If I do one or the other, the other reference still exists, and thus the object is marked to be reinserted. I'm not sure if this is a bug in DbLinq that it doesn't delete other references, or expected behavior.

Either way, in my case, the solution is to either access the table using only a single method, and delete using that method, or to delete using both methods. For the sake of getting it working, I used the second method:

```
// Delete probe
this.manufacturer.ProbeDefinition.Remove(probe);
database.ProbeDefinition.DeleteOnSubmit(probe);
database.SubmitChanges();
```

**EDIT:** Upon further work on the project and similar issues, I have found the true underlying issue of my implementation. I have a long-lived DataContext, and with how caching works (to make SubmitChanges work), you can't do this. The *real* solution is to have a short-lived DataContext, and reconnect to the database in each method.